# How to stop archive in Xcode if certain string exist in .h file?

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

I am trying to achieve the following: if certain string (#define to be precise) is exist in .h file, I 'd like to stop archive altogether and present a message on screen. Is this possible with xCode 5 ?

I tried to add the following script into pre-Action scripts for Archive in current scheme:

```
if 
{ 
    grep -Fxq "sandbox=1" ~/Desktop/Projects/Magazinereader//Classes/Archive3/InApp.h;
};
then
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
fi

if !
{ 
    grep -Fxq "//#define VerifyProduct @\"http://quazarteam.pro/verifyProduct2.php?sandbox=0\"" ~/Desktop/Projects/Magazinereader/Classes/Archive3/InApp.h;
};
then
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

but seems that it does not affect the Archive in any way. Is there a proper way to do what I want to achieve?

Comment: Try exiting with a negative number when you want to fail.

Comment: nah, exit 1 works just fine. the problem was that grep wasn't able to find the file.

Comment: the only problem that it now runs every time when i do Clean in Xcode....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to your script:

```
    # exit if you are just doing a clean
    if [[ $1 == "clean" ]]
    then
        exit
    fi
```

Make sure that $(ACTION) is passed as an argument to your script